# MySQL Workbench developer tools

Tags: python, debugging, plugins, mysql-workbench

I am currently developing an export plugin for MySQL Workbench 6.3. It is my first one.

Is there any developer tool that I can use to help me (debug console, watches, variables state, etc.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is the GRT scripting shell, which you can reach via menu -> Scripting -> Scripting Shell. This shell is mostly useful for python plugins, but also shows some useful informations from the GRT (classes, the current tree with all settings, open editors, models etc.)